# Tomcat does not start

Tags: java, tomcat, enterprise

When I try to startup my embedded tomcat my application will run until tomcat reaches following lines:

"Dez 11, 2012 3:28:06 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Information: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]"

Can anyone help me with embeddedTomcat?

Best regards

Comment: are you sure it's not running at http://localhost:8080 ?

Comment: Can you post a snippet how you start the embedded Tomcat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  Run this from the command line:

```
netstat -a -n
```

Look through there and see what ports are in the LISTEN state.  Do you see your port open?  From the logs it looks like it's running on port 8080 (ie ["http-bio-**8080**"]).  If you see it running on port 8080 then hit this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

Did you get some sort of response from apache?  Even a 404 shows it's running.

Read this:  http://www.copperykeenclaws.com/embedding-tomcat-7/

Comment: For a moment in netstat you can see port 8080 after that i will be shutted down...when you type the next time netstat... http://pastebin.com/9J8k8yqh

Comment: Put println statements around your tomcat.start().  See if it's exiting tomcat.start().  I'm pretty sure tomcat.start() invokes tomcat asynchronously.  Added a link for you to try out too.  Basically you are missing: tomcat.getServer().await();